# Default app window you land on when cmd+tab between apps on multiple monitor setup

Tags: macos, window-manager, application-switcher

I have a question regarding tab switching on MacOS.

Basically, I have a main monitor connected to my MacBook, which I use for work and my MacBook screen is used primarily for playing media in a browser.

The problem I'm having is whenever I switch Apps, say `Terminal -> Chrome`, MacOS arbitrarily picks one Chrome window (which more often than not is the one playing media on my laptop screen), and switches to that, making me accidentally refresh my media webpage.

I'm basically never touching the media browser window, but even then doing the switch from `focus on main screen browser window -> CMD + TAB to terminal on main screen -> CMD + TAB back to chrome`, seems to focus on the laptop screen, even though that one was never really focused before.

Hope the explanation makes sense and someone can help!

Answer (score 0):

What resolved my issue was going into Mission Control in System Preferences and unchecking: Displays have separate Spaces