# Can you tell iTerm2 profiles top-level windows to never show up in Cmd-Tab?

Tags: macos, iterm, application-switcher

I use a primary iTerm2 window, and some further iTerm2 windows which display specific information (e.g., like a dashboard). They live in well-visible positions on my screen, and do their own thing non-interactively. I never need to Cmd-Tab to them.

That said, of course (by Murphy's Law) whenever I do Cmd-Tab to the single iTerm2 icon showing up in the Cmd-Tab selection, I *always* end up in one of *those* windows, not in the one I constantly type in.

Is there a way to change this? I am aware of [questions like this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/428547/default-app-window-you-land-on-when-cmdtab-between-apps-on-multiple-monitor-set), but that's not it. My question is not related to screens, displays or spaces. I could imagine having some tool to mark a long-running window with some hypothetical "ignore this window in Cmd-Tab", or maybe some arcane setting in iTerm2. Those windows all have their own iTerm2 "Profile", but I could not find a setting obviously related to this in the iTerm2 profile settings.

Comment: You'd want your "dashboard" to not be in a window but something like a panel, something that is floating somewhere. But I don't think there is anything you can do, this sounds like something that is more related to the OS than iTerm2.

Answer (score 1):

You can most probably find a solution by using [Witch](https://manytricks.com/witch/).

[image]
It allows to switch through windows and use different type of sort order.

Note that you have to pay 14$ to use Witch.